# Javascript Object - prepend object to existing object

Tags: javascript, object, prepend

I have this javascript objects.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var jsObject1 = {'Mr.':'1','Mrs.':'2','Ms.':'3'} 
</script>
```

I want to add this javascript object to the beginning of the `jsObject` variable:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var jsObject2 = {'Dr.':'4','Sr.':'5','Jr.':'6'} 
</script>
```

Is there a javascript function, or perhaps jquery method for doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: What does "beginning of the variable" mean? JavaScript objects are unordered. There is no beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various utility methods available to you that will do this, such as jQuery's [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function. Or you could write your own function to achieve this as described here:

[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Not sure why you were down-voted.

Comment: Why was there a downvote?  This is the best answer. +1 for right.